# Have skip-grant-tables in mysql, would like it to be accessible for certain ips only and not able to CREATE DATABASE, DELETE, or ALTER TABLES.

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Have skip-grant-tables in mysql, would like it to be accessible for certain ips only and not able to CREATE DATABASE, DELETE, or ALTER TABLES.

Accessible for certain ips I know can do it with iptables but what about within mysql? without the skip grant table part.

I just would like that hackers will not clear the db or modify the tables etc. deletion of row is fine.

Is this possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why would you want to disable grant tables in the first place?

Comment: Untested: You may try to change ownership of the `datadir` (to prevent creation of new databases) and the table `.frm` files (to prevent ALTER, DROP) so that the `mysql` user can't write them, while having actual data / tablespace files still being owned by `mysql` ...

Comment: disabling grant tables may speed up connection time to mysql.